# "mv" command with asterisk character ("*") executed using "ssh"

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I am inexperienced with Linux, but I am learning every day.

I have this command.

```
ssh admin@$host mv repo/environments/qa/* /repo
```

Does this `*` character mean that EVERYTHING in the `environments/qa` directory will be placed into the `/repo` directory? If it already exists, it will replace it?

Sorry, but I am inexperienced with shell commands. I just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation into another language of that:

```
ssh admin@$host mv repo/environments/qa/* /repo
```

shell command (assuming a POSIX shell such as sh or bash), would look like:

```
execute("ssh", glob(split("admin@" + $host)), "mv", glob("repo/environments/qa/*"), "/repo");
```

(with the splitting done based on the characters of `$IFS`, but only on the part resulting of the expansion of `$host`; like if `$host` is `machine` and `$IFS` contains `an`, `admin@machine` would be split into `admin@m`, `chi`, and `e`, the `a` and `n` in the literal `admin` are not subject to splitting).

While you would want it to be:

```
execute("ssh", "admin@" + $host, "mv repo/environments/qa/* /repo")
```

For which the syntax in shell would be:

```
ssh admin@"$host" 'mv repo/environments/qa/* /repo'
```

`ssh` would pass that `mv repo/environment/qa/* /repo` string to `sshd` on the remote server for it to pass to the remote user's login shell to interpret, typically as:

```
execute("that-shell", "-c", "mv repo/environments/qa/* /repo")
```

And in most shells, that would do the equivalent of:

```
execute("mv", glob("repo/environments/qa/*"), "/repo")
```

To tell `mv` to move all the non-hidden files (of any type including *directory*) inside `repo/environments/qa` (itself a path relative to the current working directory of the shell process which `sshd` should have initialised to the home directory of the user) to `/repo`¹.

Some things to take out from that:

- parameter expansions like that `$host` above must almost always be quoted to avoid that split+glob.
- you want the shell on the remote system to expand that glob, so that `*` must be passed literally.
- it's important to remember that `ssh` interprets shell code remotely it doesn't run a simple command. If passed more than one argument, it will join them with spaces to make up the code to pass to the remote shell, but I recommend you pass only one code argument, if only as a reminder that it is shell code and not a simple command, and that any character special in the syntax of the remote shell will be treated as such.

  For instance, don't do `ssh host echo *.txt`, because that `*.txt` will be expanded by the local shell and if there's a file called `foo;reboot #.txt` in the current working directory for instance, that will result in `execute("ssh", "host", "echo", "foo;reboot #.txt")` being done, then `sshd` running `execute("sh", "-c", "echo foo;reboot #.txt")` and reboot.

---

<sup>¹ beware that if `/repo` does exist or is not of type *directory* (or symlink to directory) and `repo/environments/qa/*` expands to only one file, that file will be *renamed*, *moved to* (as opposed to *moved into*) `/repo`; changing `/repo` to `/repo/` would avoid that problem and report an error if `/repo` is not a directory.</sup>